# nginx weird php issue

Tags: nginx, centos, php

I just finished setting up a centos 7 server. I have installed PHP 7 with both nginx and apache. I am switching between them on demand for testing.

When I use apache, everything runs ok.

When I use nginx, all static content also works ok.

When trying PHP, all small content works ok.  When there is some large content, like the output of phpinfo() or a big SQL SELECT, the script fails without any error (browser says no data).

I checked nginx log and it says some open() to php-fpm failed because of access denied, but I do not see any error, both processes run with the same uid (apache).

Could it be some timeout issue? If not, what else?
Configurations added (example.com is the server)

### nginx.conf

```
user apache;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        # listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  examplecom www.examplecom;
        root         /var/www/example.com/;


        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }       


        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

### nginx error log

```
2017/01/07 15:15:38 [crit] 5343#0: *60 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi/1/01/0000000011" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 176.92.90.252, server: example.com, req
uest: "GET /adminer.php?sqlite=.... HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/adminer.php?...."
```

php-fpm configuration unaltered (/etc/php-fpm.conf and /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf unchanged).

Thanks.

Comment: You should really give is the full text of the error message - describing it doesn't really help. Take a look for SELinux related AVC denials in /var/log/audit/audit.log.

Comment: Provide configuration file excerpts, log file entries etc.

Comment: Added configuration and log

Comment: Is selinux enabled? Anything related to it in the logs, as hanging in asked?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider no,it is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running your `nginx` as user `apache`, you do not have access to `/var/lib/nginx/` which has `0700` access rights and is owned by user `nginx`.

So best would be to run `nginx` as user `nginx` again and alter access rights of your www root accordingly. Otherwise you would have to change the owner of `/var/lib/nginx` which could be overwritten by an update and it just feels wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was weird that it worked on small php outputs though.